# Can Azure PowerBI connect to an Elastic Query?

Tags: azure

The title says it all really.  I have an elastic pool of 20 databases and I wish to run PowerBI across the pool.  I've been able to query across all the databases with Elastic Queries, but I can't see how to connect that to PowerBI.

I think it should be possible if I stick a WebAPI over the elastic queries and connect that to PowerBI.  But is that the best way?

Comment: Answering my own question.  Looks like you can create a new database and add a bunch of 'external tables' which point to the shard map via the catalog.  You then point your PowerBI to that database.

Answer (score 3):

Answering my own question. Looks like you can create a new database and add a bunch of 'external tables' which point to the shard map via the catalog. You then point your PowerBI to that database.

Comment: Thanks for finding the answer!

Answer (score 0):

create external tables by using an elastic query. write views based on your requirements and connect those views to powerbi